# Compare numerals in batch

Tags: batch-file, numbers, compare

Posting part of the code which am looking for a workaround

```
if 09 LSS 9 (ECHO YES) ELSE (ECHO NO)
```

This command always echo's 'Yes' as it considers 09 to be less than 9. Any alternative for this command?

EDIT:

Thanks but the Modulo part is not working in the command i am trying to insert in.

Have a file test.txt which contains "1234 09" below is my command

```
set actualdate=9
for /f "usebackq Tokens=1,2,3" %%d in (test.txt) do (SET /a x=1000%%e %% 1000 & if %x% LSS %ActualDate% ECHO %%d >> test2.txt)
```

Comment: A prefix `0` indicates octal numbers, so `09` is an invalid number. You'll get unexpected results.

Comment: @EitanT `09` is an invalid number, but the results aren't unexpected. If not both values are numbers then a string compare is evaluated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [08 is less than 1, but 07 is greater than 1 in DOS/Batch. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628700/08-is-less-than-1-but-07-is-greater-than-1-in-dos-batch-why)

Comment: @jeb What I mean is the results are unexpected for the specified operation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10628922/1012053 for a full explanation.

Comment: had to put !x! instead of %x% ... thanks to Jeb

Comment: @jeb Indeed I meant that `09` is taken as a literal string, but I actually didn't know that batch knows how to "sort" strings! Apparently `09` is greater than `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code snippet is the syntax and also the percent expansion.
You can use `&` for multiple commands in one line (not the pipe `|`) or split them into multiple lines.
You can't access the variable `x` with percent expansion inside of a block, but delayed expansion works there

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set actualdate=9
for /f "usebackq Tokens=1,2,3" %%d in (test.txt) do (
   SET /a x=1000%%e %% 1000
   if !x! LSS %ActualDate% ECHO %%d >> test2.txt
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can put your numbers into variables, you can strip off the leading zero using modulo.

Try this sample:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET a=09
SET b=9

SET /a x=1000%a% %% 1000
ECHO %x%
SET /a y=1000%b% %% 1000
ECHO %y%

if %x% LSS %y% (ECHO YES) ELSE (ECHO NO)

PAUSE
```

If you try to do SET /a a=09, you'll get the following error:

> Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11) or octal (021).

Comment: How's `09` octal? `9` is not even in the octal number system.

Comment: @EitanT - going off of this here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=792.  Removed that comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: I didn't say that prefix 0 does not indicate an octal number. It's just that `09` is not octal. Now, your _last_ addition to the answer is the right explanation in my opinion, so that deserves a +1. **EDIT**: You'd better put the last comment as the _first_, because that is the main issue.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thanks for the help, could you help me with the actual command ? Have edited the original post

Comment: @TelsonAlva -- Looks like Jeb has it covered